# escape brace expansion with echo

Tags: bash, escaping, variable-expansion

I can't make this line to work on my bash script:

```
echo "VAR=$(ps ax | grep myprocess)" >> myprocess
```

How should I do to escape the `$(ps ax | grep myprocess)` expansion?

I want as a result, a `myprocess` file with this content:

```
VAR=$(ps ax | grep myprocess)
```

**EDIT**: The example I used is too simple, but it was intended to show the specific problem. Here is the real command:

```
su - -c "echo \"#!/bin/bash\nPID=$(ps ax | grep elasticsearch-${VERSION}.jar | grep -v grep | cut -f1 --delimiter=\" \" -s)\nif [ -n \"\${PID}\" ];\nthen\n\tkill \${PID}\n\techo \"ElasticSearch process killed.\"\nelse\n\techo \"ElasticSearch is not running.\"\nfi\" >> /home/user/start_elastic" user
```

Some considerations:

- I can't change to single quotes, because ${VERSION} would not be replaced.
- I tried adding a backslash like this: `\$(`, but it didn't worked. the evaluation is executed before creating the `start_elastic` file.

Comment: Simply put it inside single quotes.

Comment: or escape the `$` with a backslash

Comment: I added more info on why those options are not possible.

Comment: Is `$VERSION` the only variable you want evaluated immediately (and both instances of `$PID` plus the command substitution should be deferred)?